# Is there a package that would download release history from GitHub and create \changes in LaTeX?

Tags: dtx

In my `.dtx` file I want to have a full list of `\changes{}` lines for all releases I've made on GitHub. I don't want to put them over there manually (I will miss something). This would be better:

```
% \section{Implementation}
% \EmbedGithubReleases{yegor256/iexec}
```

This command will go to GitHub (`yegor256/iexec` is the name of repository), download the list of releases, and turn them into a list of `\changes`. Do you know such a package? Or I'm thinking into a wrong direction while this is considered a good practice: writing changes manually into `.dtx`?

Comment: l3build could do this. Do you actually need to access github or is a local list of git tags going to be enough

Comment: but I just looked at what the package does, it's a shell escape anyway so can't you just escape to a script that pipes `git tag` output through perl or python or lua or whatever to make some tex syntax?

Comment: Local list of git tags will be enough. I'm using l3build. Please, how to do it using l3build.

Comment: nothing built  but there is a hook for running Lua code before typesettig doc so you can run `git tag -n` (message but no date) or `git log --tags --simplify-by-decoration --pretty="format:%ai %d"` (date but no message) or some incantation that does both at once, then just apply some Lua patterns until it looks like tex syntax in a file input by your dtx

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you please post a full example? Where do I put this code? Into `dtx` or into `build.lua`? I'm a bit lost.